# generate Highest Number from the given Input and replacing 0 by 9 using hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Can Someone Help/suggest me how should I handle below scenario in hive.

I have one column which contain some values in which I have 0's after some digits(after 6 digits) I need to replace all these 0 by 9. and if i have 0's after 5 digits then i need to include 0 at the starting and then again need to replace 0's which comes after 6 digits.PFB some sample records and expected output.

```
       Input                    output
    1234560000000             1234569999999
     123450000000             0123459999999
      12340000000             0012349999999
       1230000000             0001239999999
```

so here basically I need to check from right to left.ie. 1234560000000
here I will start checking from right (0) and as soon as find any digit i will replace all the 0's by 9 and if digit count other then 0 is less than 6 then will add 0 in the beginning.

kindly suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split string on two parts: digits at the end and everything else, replace zeroes with 9, concatenate.

Demo:

```
with mytable as (
select '1234560000000' as input union all
select '123450000000' union all
select '12340000000' union all
select '1230000000'   
)

select lpad(concat(splitted[0], translate(splitted[1],'0','9')),13,0)
from
(
select split(regexp_replace(input,'(\\d*?)(0+)$','$1|$2'),'\\|') splitted
  from mytable
)s
```

Result

```
"1234569999999"
"0123459999999"
"0012349999999"
"0001239999999"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used hive but it looks to have all the functions I would use in some other DB

How about we `replace` all the 0 to spaces, `rtrim` the spaces off the right and `rpad` with '9' out to the original length, then `lpad` up to 13 with '0' and then `replace` any spaces (in the middle, eg if we are converting 101010000 to 000101019999) back to '0'

```
replace(
  lpad(
    rpad(
      rtrim(
        replace(num, '0', ' ')
      ),
      length(num),
      '9'
    ),
    13,
    '0'
  ),
  ' ',
  '0'
)
```

As noted, never used hive so there might be some minor syntax things to resolve here - if hive doesn't give you the length of a number by auto converting it to a string, for example, you'll need to stick something in for doing an explicit convert. You could alternatively do the log10 of the number.

I don't know of any fiddle sites that offer hive as a tester..

Comment: Thanks alot Caius Jard and leftjoin. It worked as expected . I have accepted the answer. However there are some Changes in this scenario , so I have added One new Question for the same. Requesting You. Kindly Help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71365625/exclude-minimum-6-digits-and-replace-trailing-digits-in-hive